# How to export tensorflow_hub module to use it in an installer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I'm working on a app that use a tensorflow module, currently i load tensorflow like this

```
module_path = 'https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/biggan-deep-128/1'
tf.reset_default_graph()
module = hub.Module(module_path)

inputs = {k: tf.placeholder(v.dtype, v.get_shape().as_list(), k)
          for k, v in module.get_input_info_dict().items()}
output = module(inputs)

input_z = inputs['z']
input_y = inputs['y']
input_trunc = inputs['truncation']
dim_z = input_z.shape.as_list()[1]
vocab_size = input_y.shape.as_list()[1]

initializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(initializer)
```

However i want to make my app usable for everyone, i plan to export my code to an exe (probably with pyinstaller), so i need to 'export' this model and make load it from the disk

I didn't find any information on how to it online and i'm fairly new to tensorflow so i don't really get how to do it

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly documented anywhere, but it [looks like](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/25a740b3564db8ad70ea512b1ce090aafa6a9cce/tensorflow_hub/compressed_module_resolver.py#L41) appending `?tf-hub-format=compressed` to a `https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/biggan-deep-128/1` style URL causes a redirect to the actual download:

```
$ wget 'https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/biggan-deep-128/1?tf-hub-format=compressed'
...
Length: 384022812 (366M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘1?tf-hub-format=compressed’
```

Once you have that file (renamed to e.g. `biggan-deep-128.tar`), you can probably, if I'm reading the code right, pass it to `hub.Module()`, e.g.

```
module = hub.Module('./biggan-deep-128.tar')
```

Comment: Tryed it out right now, looks like it's not the same comportement if the module is not loaded from an outside url RuntimeError: Missing implementation that supports: loader(*('./biggan-deep-128.tar',), **{})

Comment: Okay just figured it out, you have to fully extract the tar in a folder (biggan-deep-128) and then call the folder module = hub.Module('./biggan-deep-128') thanks for your help